# How do I copy or move remote files with phpseclib?

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I've just discovered phpseclib for myself and would like to use it for my bit of code. Somehow I can't find out how I could copy files from one sftp directory into an other sftp directory. Would be great if you could help me out with this.

e.g.:

copy all files of

**/jn/xml/**

to

**/jn/xml/backup/**

Answer (score 9):

```
$dir = "/jn/xml/";
$files = $sftp->nlist($dir, true);
foreach($files as $file)
{   
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
    $sftp->put($dir."backup".'/'.$file, $sftp->get($dir.'/'.$file));    
}
```

This code will copy contents from "/jn/xml/" directory to "/jn/xml/backup".

Comment: Don't know why this is downvoted , it is also a option to move files, 
After successfully moved removed original file. by 
$sftp->delete('path');

Answer (score 4):

To be able to move a file correctly with PHPSeclib, you can use

```
$sftp->rename($old, $new);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('website.com');
if (!$sftp->login('user', 'pass')) {
    exit('bad login');
}

$sftp->chdir('/jn/xml/');
$files = $sftp->nlist('.', true);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
        continue;
    }
    $dir = '/jn/xml/backup/' . dirname($file);
    if (!file_exists($dir)) {
        mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($dir . '/' . $file, $sftp->get($file));
}
```

Comment: This creates a local directory and downloads all the files in the remote sftp to the local machine, in thye directory created. Its not what Jan Neuman asked for.

Comment: @LawrenceGandhar - Looks like there was a typo. I created a directory but then wasn't writing to the newly created directory. I've updated the code. But do feel free to downvote rather than actually edit and correct in the case of obvious typos!

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do what was asked.

I used composer to import phpseclib so this is not exactly the code I tested, but from the other answers, the syntax should be correct.

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');
// connection
$sftp = new Net_SFTP('website.com');
if (!$sftp->login('user', 'pass')) {
    exit('bad login');
}
// Use sftp to make an mv
$sftp->exec('mv /jn/xml/* /jn/xml/backup/');
```

Notes:

- if any of the directories do not exist, this will fail. do `echo $sftp->exec(...` to get the errormsg.
- you will get a warning because /jn/xml/backup/ is inside /jn/xml/, I would advise moving the files to /jn/xml.bak/
- you could use 'Net/SSH2' class, since you only do a mv, and do not transfer any files. In fact, the exec is a function from the SSH2 class, and SFTP inherits it from SSH2.